# How to bind DataGridViewColumn to comboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, datagridviewcolumn

I have `dataGridView` with many columns and rows.

Now I'd like to bind content of first `column` (text) to content of `comboBox`.

How can I do this?

Comment: you have to BIND() First Column text at RowDataBound() event.

Comment: is data grid is binded to any binding source or entering data from user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the datasource of combobox like this:

```
private void BindComboBox()
{
  comboBox1.DataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;
  comboBox1.DisplayMember = "The column Name you want to bind";
}
```